# SSRS: Convert decimal to hours and minutes

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

I have a report where I want to display time in hours and minutes (17hrs 30 mins)

The dataset returns this value in decimals (Eg 17.5)

How would I convert this decimal to the format specified above (17hrs 30 mins). Is there some kind of built in function that can do this easily?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for your particular example:

```
=Floor(Fields!MyValue.Value)
    & " hrs "
    & CInt((Fields!MyValue.Value - Floor(Fields!MyValue.Value)) * 60) & " mins"
```

You may need to tweak for all possible scenarios but this should be a good starting point.

Comment: Nice one. You may have to check for when column returns null or zero