# How to convert decimal to hour and minutes in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, time, decimal

How to convert decimal to hour and minutes in sql(SSRS)

For example:

```
sum(cast([Sec_taken] as decimal(10, 2))) / 3600 AS TotalHours
```

Using this, I am getting outputs like `1.75`, `2.90` etc, but I need output like `1.45`, `2.50`

Thanks

Comment: So you want Hours.Minutes? I am a bit confused because 2.9 hours is 2 hours 54 minutes so it'd be 2.54. Just making sure I understand the output you want.

Comment: yes i need Hour.Minute. 1.50 means 1.30 in hours

Comment: asked and answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864159/ssrs-convert-decimal-to-hours-and-minutes